# Seifert matrices of cable knots

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K_{p,q}$ be a $(p,q)$-cable of the non-trivial knot $K$ in $S^3$. Let $V_{p,q}$ and $V$ denote the Seifert matrices of $K_{p,q}$ and $K$, respectively.

Is it possible to obtain a closed formula for the matrix $V_{p,q}$ in terms of $V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It also appeared in the [article](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/seifert2.pdf) of H. Seifert as Theorem II:

> Seifert, H. (1950). On the homology invariants of knots. The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, 1(1), 23-32.

Comment: Wow. It is surprising to me.

Comment: You can even draw the whole Seifert surface:
https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/cabling-a-knots-surface/

Answer (score 8):

A formula for the Seifert matrix of an arbitrary satellite can be found in the proof of Theorem 6.15 of Lickorish's "An introduction to knot theory".